# Convert String into Date java

Tags: java, date-formatting

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {       
        String testString = "14 September 11";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy");
        Date newDate = df.parse(testString); 
    }
}
```

Tell me, why do I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14 September 11"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at com.testtask.ruslan.converter.DateFormatter.main(DateFormatter.java:17)
```

Comment: It works for me.  What is your default Locale?

Comment: default Locale: ru_RU

Comment: and how do you say `september` in russian? (if the answer is not `september`, then how do you expect your date parser to know that word?)

Comment: as a side note, any proper IDE shows a warning when using that method without an explicit Locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work for English locales, but for others languages it won't. **Do not rely on default locale.** You always should specify locale explicitly for such conversions:

With `Locale.US` it passes:

```
    String testString = "14 September 11";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy", Locale.US);
    Date newDate = df.parse(testString);
```

With `new Locale("ru", "RU")` it fails:

```
    String testString = "14 September 11";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy", new Locale("ru", "RU"));
    Date newDate = df.parse(testString);
```